# webdriverio mocha How write function in wdio.conf.js if a test fails

Tags: mocha.js, webdriver-io

I am trying to write a function in wdio.conf.js that executes when a test passes.

At the end of the test, it shows all of the tests passing, however it never hits the console.log("testpassed") code shown here:

```
afterTest: function (test) {
       
        if (test.passed === true) {
            console.log("testpassed")
        }
    },
```

If I console.log - 'test' - it prints [object Object].
However, if I console log test.passed it prints undefined.

At the end of the test it shows all tests as passed.

What am I doing wrong?

Further investigation: These are the only keys returned in the 'test' array:

```
type,title,fn,body,async,sync,_timeout,_slow,_retries,timedOut,_currentRetry,pending,file,parent,ctx,_events,_eventsCount,callback,timer
```

So there doesn't seem to be a key for test.passed

Answer (score 1):

```
afterTest: function (test, context, { passed }) {

        if(passed){
            console.log("THE TEST PASSED");
        }
    },
```